# Async actions in Angular2 and Redux-Thunk

Tags: angular, redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to implement async actions (for async http requests) with redux and redux-thunk in an angular2 application. Therefore I want to use redux-thunk for async actions as explained in http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html

I can get the app running without redux-thunk using redux only following this tutorial: http://blog.ng-book.com/introduction-to-redux-with-typescript-and-angular-2/

Applying the redux-thunk in the app component like:

```
let store: Store<AppState> = createStore<AppState>(
  clientReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk),
  devtools
);
```

results in the following typscript error:

```
Error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof 'redux-thunk'' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Middleware'.
Type 'typeof 'redux-thunk'' provides no match for the signature '<S>(api: MiddlewareAPI<S>): (next: Dispatch<S>) => Dispatch<S>'
```

Does anybody know how to solve this problem ? Or know a working example of redux and redux-thunk on github ?

My code can be found on:
https://github.com/lujakob/ionic2-basic-login/tree/redux-version-1

Comment: Does doing ` applyMiddleware(thunk.default),` help the typescript compile? Sometimes the typescript imports don't play well on how some of these libraries use their default exports. Also if you can link the full file on how you are importing Thunk it may help.

Comment: The full file is: https://github.com/lujakob/ionic2-basic-login/blob/redux-version-1/app/app.ts

I also tried:  const thunk = require('redux-thunk').default;

Comment: This is a file I used it in  https://github.com/erik-sn/formcontrol/blob/master/src/index.tsx, try doing this applyMiddleware(thunk.default)

Comment: Thanks for your info. But I don't have a React application but an Angular2. And my error is a typescript "generic type" error, specific to Angular2. So, your code works of course, but does not solve my problem. Thanks anyways :-)

Comment: I myself did not find a solution so far, hence changed my implementation from plain redux to angular2-redux adopting from this example app:
https://github.com/InfomediaLtd/angular2-redux-example